# Create and cleanup instance specific rabbitMQ instances

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I have a set of microservices using springboot rest.  These microservices will be deployed in a autoscaled and load balanced environment.  One of these services is responsible for managing the system's configuration.  When other microservices startup, they obtain the configuration from this service.  If and when the configuration is updated, I need to inform all currently running microservices instances to update their cached configuration.

I am considering using RabbitMQ with a fanout exchange.  In this solution, each instance at startup will create its queue and bind that queue to the exchange.  When there is a configuration change, the configuration service will publish an update to all queues currently bound to that exchange.

However, as service instances are deleted, I cannot figure out how would I delete the queue specific to that instance.  I googled but could not find a complete working example of a solution.

Any help or advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea and solution is correct. What you just miss that those queues, created by your consumer services could be declared as `auto-delete=true`: https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html. As long as your service is UP, the queue is there as well. You stop your service, its consumers are stopped and unsubscribed. At the moment the last consumer is unsubscribed the queue is deleted from the broker.

On the other hand I would suggest to look into Spring Cloud Bus project which really is aimed for tasks like this: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-bus.

Comment: I am not using spring-config-server because our configuration is in a database that can be easily accessed from the microservices running in aws and can be easily updated through our admin interface.  All usages I found of spring cloud center around spring-config-server.  I do not know how to specify the queue name when i create the listener with annotation @RabbitListener.  I tried to create a property in properties.yml file and tried to inject it like @RabbitListener(queues = "${my_queue_name_property}") but that fails.  Any ideas?

Comment: That `@RabbitListener` comes with a `queuesToDeclare` attribute where you can specify a name and `autoDelete="true"`. And there is also a `bindings` for more features around queues and their binding to the exchange.